# Can you disavow a whole domain apart from the index page?

Tags: seo, google, links, disavow-links

Many years ago I may have bought a few sitewide links for some of my sites, these have now come back to haunt me and I need to sort them out.

I've tried to contact the owners but they're too lazy to bother changing the sites so I figure it's time to disavow the links.

But is there a way to disavow all of the sitewide links on the domain apart from on the index page and would this be a benefit to leave the index or would it still be seen as spammy?

Something like ...

```
# Contacted owner of shadyseo.com on 7/1/2012 to
# ask for link removal but got no response
domain:shadyseo.com
!shadyseo.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disavow a portion of a site.  Here is [the documentation for the disavow file format](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/10/a-new-tool-to-disavow-links.html).  It only supports three types of lines:

1. Comments that start with a `#`
2. Single URLs (each on a line by itself)
3. Domain rules such as `domain:shadyseo.com`

The disavow file does **NOT** support more complex matches such as:

- Folder matches
- Wildcard matches
- Regular expression matches.

The only way to disavow all the links on a site other than on the homepage would be to make a *complete* list of all the pages with links on the site but then not include the home page.